How do we set breakpoints in before execution vscode?
I can set breakpoints in .jdbrc
stop in com.android.Activity:1
stop at ky.c:1

VSCode doesn't respect .jdbrc configuration
{
        {
            "name": "Debug Mobile Application",
            "type": "java",
            "request": "attach",
            "hostName": "localhost",
            "projectName": "com.android.Activity",
            "processId": 19832,
            "port": "8700",
            "sourcePaths": ["java"],           
        },
}

Is there anyway I could set those break points before the program runs at jdb -attach in vscode

can you not just click in the gutter?

I am guessing you mean in a source file. I don't have the source file I just ended up decompiling a class and creating a source file with it which kind of worked but not really
